# Symfony2 - slow Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, apc

Whenever I make a simple Ajax POST request in Symfony, there seems to be a rather long waiting time before the response. Both in dev and prod environment.

[image: Slow Ajax response]

I enabled XDebug to get a better insight. Here is what's going on on the server:

[image: Slow Ajax response - Xdebug]

It seems to be Symfony's ClassLoader causing that long cycle. Page loads are similarly slow, generally over half a second.

I am running the application on localhost, on a Windows machine.

Is there any way I could reduce this execution time?

Comment: Use Prod environment i.e. `app.php` & then check if Ajax time improves.

Comment: `over half a second`? Do you think it is too much?

Comment: The above screenshots were taken in Prod in fact.

Half a second is long enough, it doesn't have the feeling of an instantaneous reaction. I tried making a similar Ajax call using the Django framework, and the response only took around 50ms there. I understand that Symfony is doing more work, but isn't there a way to cut down that 500ms to let's say 100ms?

Comment: Considering that it's running locally!

Comment: Please consider `app.php` i.e. PROD environment on your `localhost` to send requests & then share the results again.

Comment: As I said above, I did that. But if you don't believe, here's another test with PROD environment. [link](http://i.gyazo.com/6a7c7277ba1ed0c0dff9168fd056a775.png) and [link](http://i.gyazo.com/e14336b562804bdabfd6fc0f5c62b5db.png)